# Book about a kid who fakes his way into a super hero only school by saying that his power was being lucky

Tags: story-identification, books

A few years back I read a book about a male teenager who trained under an old man in the ways of being a superhero. The teenager really wanted to go to a special school for superheroes, but they only accepted students with superpowers. The teen lied to the school administration and said that he had the power of abnormal luck, and as a result he was admitted to the school. The students in the school would fight as teams against other teams of students from the school using something along the lines of a virtual reality program (or maybe they were transported into some other plane of existence, I don't remember), and there was some sort of large school tournament to see which team of students could win the most. Could anyone help me identify this book?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it is *Chance Fortune and the Outlaws* by Shane Berryhill. The plot from [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/535570.Chance_Fortune_and_the_Outlaws) seems to match really good:

> For as long as he can remember, fourteen-year-old Joshua Blevins has wanted to be a superhero. He has the brains, the passion, and the heart. There's only one problem: he doesn't have any superpowers. But Josh isn't about to let that stop him. Determined not to give up on his dream, Josh enlists the aid of his mentor, Captain Fearless, a retired costumed adventurer, to gain entrance to the Burlington Academy for the Superhuman under the false identity of Chance Fortune--a superhuman with the power of having unnaturally good luck. [...]

Also, if you are interested, I found the answer on the cached web page of this [Reddit question](https://web.archive.org/web/20140125064317/http://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1vtn35/tomtya_superhero_novel_kid_with_physical_training) (on the live version the answer is deleted).

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you so much! You made my day.